# Center a Menu in Mobile Version but not in Desktop Version

Tags: html, css, media-queries, center

Im making a Website with Media Queries. In the Mobile Version there should be a Hamburger-Dropdown Menu, where the Items are Centered, but on the Desktop Page the Menu-Items are not centered (they're normal). I've tried to add a  Tag in the HTML and give it a Id, and delete it with js, but if i do this, the whole Menu disappears. Or i gave the Center a Id and wrote in the CSS, that the display is none, but also in this Case the whole Menu disappears. And if I write text-align: center in the CSS, it works when i rezise my browser Window on PC, but not on a real mobile device.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to use media queries to make a menu centred in mobile, but not in desktop?

Comment: @JBDouble05 I just want to center the Text in the Mobile Version, but not in the Desktop Version. I've got Media Queries to get the Screen width and then apply a style to the site.

Comment: can you please post your code so far, then I can take a look at it.